# Nested grid in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have created grid using slick grid. Now as per my requirement I want to open a sub-grid on click of some element in the parent grid. To implement this I thought of adding a  after the current element and dynamically create. But since slick grid update data and top of current row dynamically (as per viewport) the new div inserted show absurd behavior on scrolling at viewport.

`var parent=s.parent().parent();
 var top=parent.css("top");
 top=parseInt(top)+parseInt("30");
 parent.after("<div class='add'style='position:relative;height:50px;width:100%;top:"+top+"px ;background-color:green;margin-bottom:20px;'></div>");`

```
    var next=parent.nextAll();
    next.each(function(index){
      if(index !=0)
      {
      var top=next[index].style.top;

      top=parseInt(top)+parseInt("50");
      next[index].style.top=top+"px";

      }`
```

Here s is the current element pointer after which I am inserting a div.

s.parent().parent() will return the pointer to row after which you want to insert element.

Then I increased the top of all row below that element. New element will be inserted properly but after scroll everything mixed up.

Comment: Is this what you're after but with the rows collapsed by default? http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html

Comment: Ryan, in this example they are just collapsing the rows of initial grid but I want a different grid to open when I click on expand and collapse that grid when I click on collapse.

Comment: If the sub grid will have different columns headers I would suggest creating a separate slickgrid instance and maybe opening it in a modal if you'd like to keep the original grid within close proximity.